# How to get a subset of has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

In my Rails 3.2 app I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many :notes` association on `Profile`. `Note` has a type on it - "urgent" or "standard". (`Note` `has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles`.)

I'd like to be able to do something like `profile.urgent_notes` without building it in a method like:

```
def urgent_notes
  urgent_notes = Array.new
  goals.each do |g|
    if g.type == "urgent"
      urgent_notes << g
    end
  end

  urgent_notes
end
```

So is there a clean way to do this by adding another association? Or would something like a scope be best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scope on Note would best best.
scope :urgent, where(type: 'urgent')

Then you can do profile.notes.urgent to get the urgent notes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a scope, here's a rewrite of your Profile method:

```
def urgent_notes
  self.goals.map {|g| g.type == 'urgent'}
end
```

You don't need to create a new array or anything. Rails and Ruby do all that work for you.